# Android UDP packets how to receive variable size packets

Tags: android, udp, packets

I have a android app which monitors for UDP packets and calls a method to process the message received. I have one problem if the incoming message is longer it will call the method to process the message. But if the incoming message is shorter it will not call the method but if I send the short message twice it will get processed or send the short message immedately after a long message it will get processed. How can I fix it? I need to handle short and long messages.

The UDP receive code which call the method for a long message but not for a short message;

```
        class Server extends Thread {


    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
               int port = 8888;
               // Create a socket to listen on the port.
                 dsocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
               // Create a buffer to read datagrams into.
                byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
          // Create a packet to receive data into the     buffer
          DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, uffer.length);
                while (true) {
                           try {


                 // Wait to receive a datagram
                   dsocket.receive(packet);
                   //Convert the contents to a string,
    String msg = new String(buffer, packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength());
                              if (msg !=null)
                               {
                                  call(msg);
                                   msg=null;
                               }
                      // Reset the length of the packet before reusing it.
                               packet.setLength(buffer.length);



                           } catch (Exception e) {
                                   dsocket.close();
                                    break; }
                              }

            } catch (Exception e) {
              dsocket.close();  e.printStackTrace();}

           }
     }


    public void call(String mg) {
    int v;
    int sq=0;  // store squence no of the calls
    int indxs=0;  // start alarm msg index

    boolean fnd; // alarm msg filter flg
    char Sqchar1;   // squnce no of the call
    char Sqchar2;   // squnce no of the call
    char Sqchar3;   // squnce no of the call
    int pospri; // default position 8 of priority for one digit seqence no
    String pstr = null; // alarm msg string without filter
    boolean aflg =false; // alarm msg found flg becomes true
         boolean retval = false; // stop same active sequence msg
    int sqnum; // defualt sq to one digit

    int lstr = mg.length();
         int indxe= lstr; // end alarm msg index
// typica string mg = 145 ($\M A 1 5 "bla bla")// valid alarm msg
// typical string mg =  88 ($\M A 12 6 "bla bla")// valid alarm msg
// typical string mg =  127 ($\M A 123 1 "bla bla")// valid alarm msg
// typical string mg =  1111 ($\M A 130 2 "bla bla")// valid alarm msg
    // typical string mg = 148 ($\M N 1)// valid CANCEL msg  
    // typical string mg =  90 ($\M N 12)// valid CANCEL msg
    // typical string mg =  130 ($\M N 123)// valid CANCEL msg
    // typical string mg =  1115 ($\M N 130)// valid CANCEL msg

    // NON Valid string mg = 456 
    // NON Valid string mg = 113 ($\C  x  n " bla bla")

    //serach for alarm string
    for(int i=0; i< lstr; i++)
    {
        char schar = mg.charAt(i);
        if(schar=='$')
        {

            rHandler.post(rRunnable);
            pstr = mg.substring(i, (lstr-1));
            aflg =true; break;
        }
      }

      if(aflg)
        {
        char achar = pstr.charAt(2);  // indicateas alarm msg
        char ACchar = pstr.charAt(4);  // indicateas alarm active

        if(achar =='M' && ACchar == 'A')
        {
            Sqchar1= pstr.charAt(6);
            if(pstr.charAt(7)!=' ')
            {
                sqnum=2;
                Sqchar2= pstr.charAt(7);
                pospri = 9;
            }
            else
            {
                sqnum=1;
                Sqchar2=' ';
                pospri = 8;
                sq = Character.getNumericValue(Sqchar1);

            }

            if(sqnum==2)
            {
                if(pstr.charAt(8)!=' ')
                {
                    //squnum =3

                    pospri = 10;
                    Sqchar3= pstr.charAt(8);
                    int sq1 = Character.getNumericValue(Sqchar1);
                    int sq2 = Character.getNumericValue(Sqchar2);
                    int sq3 = Character.getNumericValue(Sqchar3);
                    sq= (sq1 * 100) + (sq2 * 10) + sq3;

                }
                else
                {
                    int sq1 = Character.getNumericValue(Sqchar1);
                    int sq2 = Character.getNumericValue(Sqchar2);
                    sq= (sq1 *10) + sq2;
                    pospri = 9;
                }
            }

            int plen = pstr.length();
             fnd=false;
            for(int x=0; x<plen; x++)
            {
                char ichar = pstr.charAt(x);
                if( ichar== '"' && !fnd )
                {
                    indxs = x+1; fnd = true;
                }
                else
                if(ichar == '"' && fnd)
                {
                    indxe = x; break;
                }
            }



            String amsg = pstr.substring(indxs, indxe);
            // stop repetated msgs
            if(sqlist[sq]== sq)
            {
                retval = true;
            }

            if (!retval)
            {
                sqlist[sq] = sq;
                alarmlist[sq] = amsg;
                clrlist[sq]=Character.toString(pstr.charAt(pospri));
                sound(clrlist[sq]); tHandler.post(tRunnable);

            }
          }
          else
          if(achar =='M'&& ACchar == 'N')
           {
            int clen =pstr.length();
            if(clen ==7 )
            {
                Sqchar1= pstr.charAt(6);
                sq= Character.getNumericValue(Sqchar1);
            }
            else
            if(clen ==8 )
            {
                Sqchar1= pstr.charAt(6);
                Sqchar2= pstr.charAt(7);
                int sq1 = Character.getNumericValue(Sqchar1);
                int sq2 = Character.getNumericValue(Sqchar2);
                sq= (sq1 * 10) + sq2;
            }
            else
            if(clen ==9 )
            {
                Sqchar1= pstr.charAt(6);
                Sqchar2= pstr.charAt(7);
                Sqchar3= pstr.charAt(8);
                int sq1 = Character.getNumericValue(Sqchar1);
                int sq2 = Character.getNumericValue(Sqchar2);
                int sq3 = Character.getNumericValue(Sqchar3);
                sq= (sq1 * 100) + (sq2 * 10) + sq3;
            }



            sqlist[sq] = 0;
            alarmlist[sq] = null;
            clrlist[sq]= null; cHandler.post(cRunnable);

        }
        else
       {
           return;
       }


            list.clear();

            int elementsCount = alarmlist.length;
            v=0;
            for(int i=0; i < elementsCount; i++)
            {
                String disp =alarmlist[i];
                if(disp != null)
                {

                    list.add(v, disp+ "#" + clrlist[i]);
                    v++;
                }
            }
            write(list, "/mnt/sdcard/msg.tmp"); dHandler.post(dRunnable);
        } //alarm msg


     return;
     }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense; and your code does not behave as described. `msg` cannot possibly be null at the point you are testing it; and there is nothing in this code that is sensitive to the message length in different ways.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Since posting the question I had been trying to solve it. It appears something is wrong with my void method. When conditions in the methods are not met it is not returning to the calling thread. Hence I am going to add a empty return statement and try.

Comment: HI EJP,   Still I could not solve the problem. I am posting the method. Can you check if anything is wrong in the logic or holding it. Just let you know that I am new to Java & Android.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It is nothing do with this code. It is do with the way I was sending the UDP Packets. I wrote a C++ program to send the UDP Packets and I had a bug on it when I was sending shorter messages. As soon as I fixed it, the app is working fine.